# Using Epplus to import data from an Excel file to SQL Server database table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014, epplus-4

I've tried implementing thishttps://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/easy_excel_interaction_pt6 on an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application.

//SEE CODE BELOW

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        var regPIN = DB.AspNetUsers.Where(i => i.Id == user.Id).Select(i => i.registrationPIN).FirstOrDefault();
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            var excelFile = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/BulkImports"),regPIN + extension);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(excelFile))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(excelFile);
            }
            else if (file.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || file.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                file.SaveAs(excelFile);//WORKS FINE
                //BEGINING OF IMPORT
                FileInfo eFile = new FileInfo(excelFile);
                using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(eFile))
                {
                    if (!eFile.Name.EndsWith("xlsx"))//Return ModelState.AddModelError()
                    { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incompartible Excel Document. Please use MSExcel 2007 and Above!"); }
                    else
                    {
                        var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                        if (worksheet == null) { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong Excel Format!"); }// return ImportResults.WrongFormat;

                        else
                        {
                            var lastRow = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                            while (lastRow >= 1)
                            {
                                var range = worksheet.Cells[lastRow, 1, lastRow, 3];
                                if (range.Any(c => c.Value != null))
                                { break; }
                                lastRow--;
                            }
                            using (var db = new BlackBox_FinaleEntities())// var db = new BlackBox_FinaleEntities())
                            {
                                for (var row = 2; row <= lastRow; row++)
                                {
                                    var newPerson = new personalDetails
                                    {
                                        identificationType = worksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString(),
                                        idNumber = worksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value.ToString(),
                                        idSerial = worksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value.ToString(),
                                        fullName = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value.ToString(),
                                        dob = DateTime.Parse(worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value.ToString()),
                                        gender = worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value.ToString()
                                    };
                                    DB.personalDetails.Add(newPerson);
                                    try { db.SaveChanges(); }
                                    catch (Exception) { }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }//END OF IMPORT
                ViewBag.Message = "Your file was successfully uploaded.";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "Error: Your file was not uploaded. Ensure you upload an excel workbook file.";
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Error: Your file was not uploaded. Ensure you upload an excel workbook file.";
            return View();
        }
    }
```

[See Picture Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBtNN.png)
Any help would be greatly appreciated mates.

Comment: Are any of the `Cells.Value` you are referencing when creating newPerson null?  If that is the case call `.ToString()` will certainly cause a null reference exception.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the excel file and now it has no empty cells, also, i added some validation to the sheet.

Now, am able to submit the form with no errors, excel file uploads, not entries to the targeted database table.

Suggestion...Maybe am handling the HttpPostedFileBase and FileInfo wrongly. I really don't have to "Upload" to my server like how its implemented here [https://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/easy_excel_interaction_pt6]

Else, help me implement the view for [https://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/easy_excel_interaction_pt6] approach

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
public bool readXLS(string FilePath)
{
    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        //get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
        string queryString = "INSERT INTO tableName VALUES";        //Here I am using "blind insert". You can specify the column names Blient inset is strongly not recommanded
        string eachVal = "";
        bool status;
        for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
        {
            queryString += "(";
            for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
            {
                eachVal = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString().Trim();
                queryString += "'" + eachVal + "',";
            }
            queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Length - 1, 1);    //removing last comma (,) from the string
            if (row % 1000 == 0)        //On every 1000 query will execute, as maximum of 1000 will be executed at a time. 
            {
                queryString += ")";
                status = this.runQuery(queryString);    //executing query
                if (status == false)
                    return status;
                queryString = "INSERT INTO tableName VALUES";
            }
            else
            {
                queryString += "),";
            }
        }
        queryString = queryString.Remove(queryString.Length - 1, 1);    //removing last comma (,) from the string
        status = this.runQuery(queryString);    //executing query
        return status;
    }
}
```

Details: http://sforsuresh.in/read-data-excel-sheet-insert-database-table-c/